# Windows 10 consumes all free memory if hyper-v is On

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

Windows 10 is consuming all free memory when `docker desktop` is installed and `hyper-v` is on. I don't have any container running right now but memory usage is around 99%. I have 24GB of RAM on the system.

If I reboot the system, memory usage eventually gets to 99% after sometime (no containers are running).

If I disable Hyper-V then the memory usage always below 50%. But I need it enabled so I can use Docker desktop.

Is there anything that can be done to reduce the memory usage when docker desktop isn't running? I've already tried `.wslconfig` and `wsl --shutdown` but still memory usages is 99%.

Task Manager:

The process tab doesn't show anything that's consuming memory.

[image]

RamMap:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is the culprit (even if no containers are running). Quitting docker releases memory. After quitting docker memory usage went from 90% to 35%.

Docker memory usage isn't shown correctly in task manager. It shows that it's consuming 3GB but its consuming 99% of memory. Quitting docker is when all memory gets released.

Update: It's a [bug](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12877) with docker version 4.11.0 and 4.11.1. Upgrading to latest version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a database in one of your containers, and have dynamic memory enabled, it will tend to eat up as much memory as it can get.

You can [limit](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/limiting-memory-usage-in-wsl-2/#1-create-wslconfig) WSL memory usage using `.wslconfig`

Comment: .wslconfig doesn't help at all. I don't have any containers running but docker is consuming 90% of memory.